# ionic 2 local storage get and display the data

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, ionic2, local-storage

hi i cant access my data in localstorage , it always gives me error . i need help in displaying my datas in my home . thank you for your help :)

**Error:**

Typescript Error
Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

this.user = JSON.parse(this.storage.get(this.key));
prompt.present();

**Typescript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

/**
 * Generated class for the CrudPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-crud',
  templateUrl: 'crud.html',
})
export class CrudPage {

  user: any = [] ;
  key: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
  public navParams: NavParams,
  public viewCtrl: ViewController,
  public alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.forEach( (value) => {
      this.user.push(value);
    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CrudPage');
  }

  add() {
    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add User',
      message: "Enter information of the user",
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: 'name'
        },
        {
          name: 'password',
          placeholder: 'password'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked!');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
            let key = data.name + data.password;
            this.storage.set(key, JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(data);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    this.user = JSON.parse(this.storage.get(this.key));
    prompt.present();
  }

  delete(key){
    this.storage.remove(key);
  }

  update(key){

  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--
  Generated template for the CrudPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Crud</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <button ion-button clear icon-start color="dark" (click)="add()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle">Add User</ion-icon>
    </button>

    <br>

  <ion-grid text-center>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-100>
        USERS
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <strong>User Name</strong>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <strong>Password</strong>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <strong>Action</strong>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let users of user" text-center>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <p>{{users.name}}</p>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <p>{{users.password}}</p>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-33>
        <button ion-button clear icon-start color="dark" (click)="delete(users.name+users.password)">
          <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button ion-button clear icon-start color="dark" (click)="update(users.name+users.password)">
          <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

Please help :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this.storage.get(this.key) returns a promise, you have to do that:

```
this.storage.get(this.key).then(value => {
    this.user = JSON.parse(value);
});
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

Comment: thank you for your response :) i got it , thanks for the help :)

Comment: can i ask what is the onload() function in ionic ? because every time i click the add, it doesn't add directly , i have to load the page for it to add . what should i do ? thank you :)